# How do I get populate hidden text fields with values from spans in order to access the values?

Tags: javascript, html

I'll preface by saying I've seen multiple questions with solutions on here and other sites but none seem to be working. I assume there's something I'm missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the HTML file:

```
<form action="/stopwatch" method="post">
    <label for="timer">Choose a Timer:</label>

    <select name="timer" id="timer">
        {% for timer in timers %}
        <option id="{{ timer["timer"] }}" value="{{ timer["timer"] }}">{{ timer["timer"] }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>

    <div id="display">
        <p><span id="hours">00</span>:<span id="minutes">00</span>:<span id="seconds">00</span>:<span id="centis">00</span></p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <button type="button" id="start" class="btn btn-primary">Start</button>
        <button type="button" id="stop" class="btn btn-primary">Stop</button>
        <button type="submit" id="reset" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="populate()">Save and Reset</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="inputHours"></input>
        <input id="inputMinutes"></input>
        <input id="inputSeconds"></input>
        <input id="inputCentis"></input>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the JS file. I feel like I've tried every every combination of "innerHTML" "innerText" "textContent" tags to no avail. Also tried setting things to variables first before assigning the values.

```
function populate()
{
    document.getElementById("inputHours").value = document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("inputMinutes").value = document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("inputSeconds").value = document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("inputCentis").value = document.getElementById("centis").innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: Whats the problem it all works: https://jsfiddle.net/ye9b02q6/1/

Comment: For clarity, does "_access the values_" in the title mean **of the POST'd form**?

Answer (score 0):

Only form fields with a `name` attribute defined for them will submit their data along with the rest of the form and your `input` form fields don't have a `name`.

Also, you don't have any "hidden" form fields - you have empty `input` fields. To make a hidden form field, you need `input type="hidden"`. And, `input` does not get a closing tag.

You probably also want to stop the form submission until after you've set the values you want. **Or, if you aren't actually trying to submit data anywhere, then you shouldn't be using a `submit` button, which will cause your page to reload from scratch and should just be using a `button` without a form `action`.**

```js
// Get your DOM references just once:
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const hoursInput = document.getElementById("inputHours");
const hoursElement = document.getElementById("hours");
const minutesInput = document.getElementById("inputMinutes");
const minutesElement = document.getElementById("minutes");
const secondsInput = document.getElementById("inputSeconds");
const secondsElement = document.getElementById("seconds");
const centisInput = document.getElementById("inputCentis");
const centisElement = document.getElementById("centis");
    
form.addEventListener("submit", populate);

function populate(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Stops the native form submission of a submit button

  // Populate the hidden form fields
  hoursInput.value = hoursElement.textContent;
  minutesInput.value = minutesElement.textContent;
  secondsInput.value = secondsElement.textContent;
  centisInput.value = centisElement.textContent;
    
  //form.submit(); // Submit the form
}
```

```html
<form action="/stopwatch" method="post">
    <label for="timer">Choose a Timer:</label>

    <select name="timer" id="timer">
        {% for timer in timers %}
        <option id="{{ timer["timer"] }}" value="{{ timer["timer"] }}">{{ timer["timer"] }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>

    <div id="display">
        <p><span id="hours">00</span>:<span id="minutes">00</span>:<span id="seconds">00</span>:<span id="centis">00</span></p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <button type="button" id="start" class="btn btn-primary">Start</button>
        <button type="button" id="stop" class="btn btn-primary">Stop</button>
        <button type="submit" id="reset" class="btn btn-primary">Save and Reset</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <!-- Add type="hidden" to the input elements if you really want hidden form fields -->
        <input id="inputHours" name="hours">
        <input id="inputMinutes" name="minutes">
        <input id="inputSeconds" name="seconds">
        <input id="inputCentis" name="centis">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: @ikiK Yes, of course my form submits - it's supposed to. And, the original code does not work because none of the `input` fields that don't have a `name` attribute on them will transfer their data anywhere. The input elements may get data in them, but that data won't get submitted.

Comment: I know very well how forms works. See my snippet in question comment. It works as Op has posted it. Values are populated as they should be. And no I will not remove my down vote.

Comment: @ikiK Apparently you don't because the question isn't about the `input` elements getting populated, it's about the data getting submitted, which won't happen without the `name` attribute. Also, if the OP isn't interested in data submission, then the problem is that the form is being submitted when it shouldn't be - both addressed in my answer.

Comment: Actually "access data"  could mean many things. You made an assumption, that actually could be the answer. But it is definitely not clear from question. I will remove my down vote. But this is guessing.

Comment: @ikiK It's not guessing because I have provided answers for both possibilities.

Comment: Hey there @ScottMarcus! Thanks for taking the time to look at this.

You are correct that I want to submit the data to a Post. It runs a SQL query to add the time to a time elapsed database.

Just a few quick questions:

1) Why does the function need "event" in it's parenthesis?

2) To be clear, the submission needs to be stopped and then resubmitted because without that, the submission happens immediately before anything else?

Thanks again.

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing wrong here but the text fields still won't populate.

The addition of names does allow for the data to be submitted to POST if I manually populate the fields so thank you for that!

Comment: @RussellFeinstein As I stated, if you use a `submit` button, the page will POST to the location you've specified in your `action`. If that is the same page as the one that is already loaded, the page will just reload and any data you might have populated the fields with would be lost.

Comment: @RussellFeinstein The `event` in parenthesis is a named argument because all event handlers are automatically passed a reference to the event that triggered them. You can call the argument anything you like, but `event` or `e` are the most common. Accessing the event allows you to stop the `submit` event so you can populate the fields.

Comment: @RussellFeinstein I've moved your inline `onsubmit` event attribute over to JavaScript with `form.addEventListener()`, which is the preferred approach. And, I'm going to comment out the `form.submit()` line in my code above just to show you that the fields do populate with this code.

Comment: @ScottMarcus thanks again for helping me with this. Really appreciate it. Even with your adjustments, the form still seems to be submitting without populating fields. The error happens after POSTing. It happens in a function that is ensuring the values in the populated fields are integers. The returned error is: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' - Sorry if there's something obvious I'm missing. This is a project for an online coding class and the whole thing is very "search the internet and figure out what you need" and something about this isn't clicking.

Comment: @RussellFeinstein That error doesn't necessarily mean that there's no data. It means that you are trying to convert a string to an int and the string isn't convertible to that. I think you are assuming that because you can't get your int that there is no data, and that's not the case.

Comment: @ScottMarcus but if form submission is off, why is it POSTing and why do the fields not populate?

Comment: @RussellFeinstein In my example above, form submission is off and it does NOT POST and the fields DO populate as you can see. You need to remove the `onsubmit` attribute from your HTML and replace it with the `.addEventListener()` code I'm showing.